# Can you use Adobe after effect to create the animation like the Prezi presentation?

Tags: after-effects, prezi

By the 'Prezi-like animation' I mean that your canvas rotate/zoom/shift to the tiny little portion in a sequential manner.

P.S.: The question is not limited to AE. Any animation sw would be relevant.

Some suggest [HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732997/prezi-like-web-interface-flash-or-html5), but that targets web design (my purpose is only creating some animation for self entertainment.)

Answer (score 1):

Still, if HTML5 is an option have a look at [layerJS](http://layerjs.org), an open source library which can create **Prezi-like** web interfaces. It even allows **multiple layers** if you need some elements to move independently of each other.

It's super **simple**: just add a **stage** div put one or more layers in and add as many **frames** as you want between you can have **zooming, panning and rotating transitions**.

The HTML code would look like this:

```
<div data-wl-type="stage">
  <div data-wl-type="layer" data-wl-layout-type="canvas">
    <div data-wl-type="frame" data-wl-name="frame1" data-wl-x="100" data-wl-width="1000" data-wl-rotation="45" ...>
    </div>
    <div data-wl-type="frame" ...>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You could do it manually. A little tedious, but you would place your text layers in 3d space and push your camera around. You will spend a lot of time tweaking everything like the things in the visible things in the background and the easing moves into and away from the text.

Sure Target is free and could be a big time saver. You basically use it to square up the camera to null objects and it takes a lot of the tedium out of the process, even though you have to spend a few minutes up front to figure out how it works.

http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorial/energetic_titles/

Answer (score 0):

[Webpgr](http://webpgr.com) does offer this. It's HTML5 based and comes with a Photoshop-like online editor. It's in beta but you can request an account.